# Split a column with two different delimiters in three column in one line of code

Tags: python, pandas

Can I split a column into three columns in one line even when the delimiter is different?

Example

```
ColA
chr2:000001-000002
```

Expected

```
Chr    Start      end
chr2   000001     000002
```

The code I am looking for should be something like this

```
df[['Chr','Start','End']] = ...
```

I have been told that this is impossible. I have been trying part of the day without luck.

Comment: Did you split on colon and dash and your code didn't work? Show your code.

Comment: That is the point, I don't know how to split when there are different

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [pd.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA':'chr2:000001-000002'}, index=[0])

df[['Chr', 'Start', 'End']] = df['ColA'].str.split(':|-', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
                 ColA   Chr   Start     End
0  chr2:000001-000002  chr2  000001  000002
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[['Chr', 'Start', 'End']] = df['ColA'].str.split('[:-]',expand = True)

df 
                 ColA   Chr   Start     End
0  chr2:000001-000002  chr2  000001  000002
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2[['Chr','Start','End']] = df['ColA'].str.replace(":","-").str.split("-", expand=True)
```

out:

```
    Chr   Start     End
0  chr2  000001  000002
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly using `split`, but if your format is always consistent (which seems to be your case), a nice approach might be to use `str.extract` with named capturing groups:

```
df['ColA'].str.extract(r'(?P<Chr>\w+):(?P<Start>\d+)-(?P<End>\d+)')
```

Output:

```
    Chr   Start     End
0  chr2  000001  000002
```